# Ext4: How to Recover a single permanently deleted file

Tags: ext4

On /dev/sda6 (non primary) partition, I have a dir called /bean. I usually download some videos from Google photos there - which are in zip format called Photos-001.zip. I then copy those to an external drive, delete the zip file, videos from Google & Google trash - all permanently - to make space on Google photos.
But I made a mistake once. I deleted zip without copying to external drive , and from Google photos & trash. To save any damage I immediately unmounted the partition & removed it from fstab. Nothing's been written to that partition ever since.
I've used a 5 year old YouTube video on ext4magic & a recent video on how to use TestDisk. I can see the existence of deleted file, inode of dir & file,  & tried to recover. Both tools create /bean dir but not files.
Can someone please help that one single zip?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: For ext4 you can use `extundelete` from the repositories. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/extundelete.1.html